# Can not conditionally increment value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

After an Ajax call using jQuery, and success in receiveing the `res` I'd like to increment value of a `<p>` when a `plus` response is receive, and decrement it when a `minus` response is received.

Here is my code:

```
    success: function(res) {
        var oldLikes = $("#like_count").val();
        console.log('oldLikes is:', oldLikes);
        console.log('response:', res);
        if (res =='minus') {
            $(function() {
                $("#like_count").val(oldLikes--) ;
            });               

        } else if (res == 'plus') {
            $(function() {
                $("#like_count").val(oldLikes++) ;
            });
        }  else {
            console.log('nothing');
        }
   }
```

The html part:

`<p id="like_count">4</p>`

While I can see the response `minus` or `plus` are being received but the value is not changed on html paragraph.

I have also tried  `var oldLikes = $("#like_count").text();` and used some strings instead of incrementing values, but nothing is changed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: its not val / value, its html

Comment: Please don't edit your question unless there's a problem with spelling or formatting. Right now, the question doesn't bare any resemblance to its original format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually quite a few problems here.

1. You can't use `val()` on `<p>` elements. It is reserved for form inputs.
2. You need to parse the innerHTML value of the `<p>` tag to be an integer.
3. `oldLikes++` and `oldLikes--` will return the original number, and *then* subtract or add one. You should reverse the operators so that they are `++oldLikes` and `--oldLikes` respectively.

Here's a revised version of your code:

```
success: function(res) {

    var oldLikes = parseInt( $("#like_count").text() );

    if (res =='minus')
    {
        $("#like_count").text( --oldLikes ) ;
    }
    else if( res == 'plus' )
    {
        $("#like_count").val( ++oldLikes ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it does not change the innter html of `p`.

Comment: Works great. Thanks Ben!

Comment: Actually `parseInt` is not required, as JS infers integer from text while incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

Few issues with your code:

1. `$(function() {` waits for document to be ready and it makes no sense in the context.
2. oldLikes is not assigned when using `--` or `++` you are assigning the same value (before it actualy changes)
   `VAR--` changes AFTER, `--VAR` changes BEFORE.

```js
function test() {
  var res = 'minus';
  var oldLikes = $("#like_count").val();
  if (res == 'minus') {
      $("#like_count").val(--oldLikes);
  } else if (res == 'plus') {
      $("#like_count").val(++oldLikes);
  } else {
    console.log('nothing');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="like_count">
<button type="button" onclick="test()">TEST</button>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Please see the updated question with the whole function.

Comment: @qliq It doesn't work because `val()` won't work on `<p>` elements. You need to use `text()` per my answer.

Comment: @BenM i have no P element

Comment: @qliq if you click RUN CODE SNIPPET, you will see it works.